# Hypermetabolism in Twilight Imperium

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

In Twilight Imperium 4th Edition, the card Hypermetabolism reads:

> During the status phase, gain 2 command tokens instead of 1

You already get 2 command tokens during the status phase, and is likely a misprint.  This has been discussed on [many](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1835042/hyper-metabolism-misprint) [threads](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1833702/hype-metabolism-and-status-phase), but is there an official errata from FFG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The [living rules reference v1.1](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/3a/fc/3afce41b-b757-4dc8-b005-3a5efffd0fad/ti4_living_rules_reference_v1_1.pdf) contains the errata:

> HYPER METABOLISM
>
> The text of the “Hyper Metabolism” technology should read as follows:
> “During the status phase, gain 3 command tokens instead of 2.”